# Belgium keeper Thibaut Courtois touching his effort wide after he ran clear

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> England - who desperately missed absent captain and leading World Cup scorer Harry Kane - barely threatened, though Marcus Rashford should have equalised, Belgium keeper Thibaut Courtois touching his effort **wide after he ran clear**.
>
> (From [BBC.com](https://www.bbc.com/sport/football/44439312))

This a remark on BBC news after England losing to Belgium. What I can't understand is the last sentence describing the movement from Belgium keeper. I am not able to visualize what 'wide after he ran clear' is.

Answer (score 1):

> ...though Marcus Rashford should have equalised, Belgium keeper Thibaut Courtois touching his effort wide after he ran clear.

This is describing what the writer thoughts was England's best chance at scoring a goal (thereby bringing the game to a draw).

What happened, apparently:

1. Marcus Rashford "ran clear" (that is, had a breakaway).
2. Rashford shot the ball toward the goal.
3. The Belgian goalkeeper "touched the shot wide" (that is, put his hand on the ball just enough to deflect the shot wide of the goal post).

Comment: Thank you. Why does the writer use the wide, an adjective rather than an adverb.

Comment: It seems like an adverbial usage to me. NOAD reads: **wide** (*adverb*) - far from a particular point or mark : *a shot that went wide to the right*.

Comment: Oh, and you should [wait longer before accepting an answer](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer).